# How do I calculate the next run time for my event provider?

Tags: c#, events, datetime, scheduled-tasks, timespan

I am trying to calculate a start time for an event provider.

I have 3 variables:

```
DateTime eventStartTime
DateTime currentTime
TimeSpan timeBetweenEvents
```

`eventStartTime` is the desired start time at any given day e.g. "6:00AM"
`currentTime` is the current time
`timeBetweenEvents` is the TimeSpan between event executions

This is my code:

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeToStart(DateTime eventStartTime, DateTime currentTime, TimeSpan timeBetweenEvents)
{
    TimeSpan timeToStart;
    // e.g. if it is before 6:00AM today
    if(DateTime.Now < merchantEventStartTime)
      timeToStart = merchantEventStartTime - DateTime.Now;
    // otherwise process at timeToStart + ISO8601 specified merchantEventProviderSchedule
    else
      timeToStart = merchantEventStartTime - DateTime.Now + merchantEventProviderSchedule;
    return timeToStart;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for downvotes?

Comment: also interested in why OP was downvoted twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple while loop solves this by incrementing the eventStartTime until it is AFTER the current time.  This is vulnerable to some data issues, but works for what I need it to do.

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeToStart(DateTime eventStartTime, DateTime currentTime, TimeSpan timeBetweenEvents)
{
    while(eventStartTime < currentTime)
        eventStartTime = eventStartTime.Add(timeBetweenEvents);

    return eventStartTime - currentTime;
}
```

A unit test verifying my results:

```
public void TestGetTimeToStart()
{
    //5AM currentTime
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    var timeToStartBefore6am = AlertingService.GetTimeToStart(
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 6, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 5, 0, 0),
        XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT12H"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(timeToStartBefore6am);
    Assert.AreEqual(timeToStartBefore6am, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

    //5PM currentTime
    var timeToStartBefore6pm = AlertingService.GetTimeToStart(
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 6, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 17, 0, 0),
        XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT12H"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(timeToStartBefore6pm);
    Assert.AreEqual(timeToStartBefore6pm, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

    //7PM currentTime
    var timeToStartAfter6pm = AlertingService.GetTimeToStart(
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 6, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 19, 0, 0),
        XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT12H"));
    Assert.IsNotNull(timeToStartAfter6pm);
    Assert.AreEqual(timeToStartAfter6pm, new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0));
}
```